# Connecting remote mysql database to local mysql databse?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I want to write a php code to be embedded in drupal7 module.

I want to call a procedure which can copy the newly generated data in local mysql database to the remote mysql database.

When data is inserted in tables 'A' of my local data base it should be copied to the specific table 'B' of the remote mysql server's database.

Table 'A' is on local host.

Table 'B' is on remote server.

insert data on 'A' -> copied data in 'B'

Is this possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: <?php

$server = "***.***.***.***"; 
$dbname = "dbname"; 
$user = "username"; 
$password = "password"; 
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($dbname);  
?>

Comment: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

I get the above error when i try to run php.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger + `Federated tables` should do the trick:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will surely try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for automatic backups or master->slave duplication, there are ways to accomplish that without touching a line of code.

See here for how:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

This is my personal favorite:
http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/05/how-to-setup-mysql-replication-a-simple-guide.html

Related post:
[phpmyadmin synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115374/phpmyadmin-synchronize)

Still need help doing that? Post.