# Where is the Synchronize tab under PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have read in multiple places about the Synchronize tab in PhpMyAdmin which helps to sync two tables but I am unable to find where that option is? I downloaded the latest PhpMyAdmin and even checked on online demo but seems this feature is nicely hidden, keeps escaping me or requires to turn on some configuration to see it. Here is the link to the online PhpMyAdmin demo. Let me know where you can find it.
http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/

Attaching a snapshot of what I am looking to find
[image: Synchronize Tab PhpMyadmin]
Synchronize Tab PhpMyAdmin from http://toyhouse.cc/profiles/blogs/synchronize-databases-by-phpmyadmin

Note: I am not looking for Replication feature which has its own tab but the Synchronize feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the config option described in the article you posted?

Comment: @tlenss What do you mean?

Comment: i was referring to `$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;`. But if the feature has been removed it won't help much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been removed as of phpMyAdmin 4.0.0. It had many shortcomings.

Comment: Did phpMyAdmin 3.5.7 had it? On a tangent, will it be ok to download from http://www.oldapps.com/phpmyadmin.php or if any other urls you know of?

Comment: Download from a safe place: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php and choose 3.5.8.2.

Comment: Can you expand on the shortcomings ?

Comment: For the shortcomings, see https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/phpMyAdmin_4#Synchronise_db.27s

Comment: @RobertSinclair Replication is a different feature, we were talking about Synchronize.